# Change the opacity of TextField backgroundcolor not for text - Swift, UIKIT

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, textfield

I am looking the ways to change the opacity of TextField BackgroundColor programatically.

When I do:

`UITextfield.layer.opacity` - it changes the opacity of text as well.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You need to play with color's alpha

```
textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

**Solution 2:**

You can't partition the opacity of one control , so you need to place a background view behind it and play with it's opacity